# Join products table with prices table, for products with n valid prices

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables of products and prices:

**table: product**

```
productID   
---------
1
2
3
4
5
```

**table: price**

```
priceID     productID   started     expires
-------------------------------------------
1           1           2011-11-05  NULL    
2           1           2011-11-05  2011-11-20
3           2           2011-11-05  NULL
4           3           2011-11-05  NULL
5           3           2011-11-06  2011-11-08
```

and I want to join them in such a way that:

1. Only one price per product
2. Prices are valid if `price.started <= NOW() AND ( price.expires >= NOW() ||  price.expires IS NULL )`
3. If more than one price is valid for one product, price with higher `price.priceID` should be chosen
4. If no price is valid, still show product info

These four criteria define the *most valid* (for luck of a better term) of valid prices. So for `NOW() == 2011-11-09` the end result should be:

```
priceID     productID   started     expires
-------------------------------------------
2           1           2011-11-05  2011-11-20
3           2           2011-11-05  NULL
4           3           2011-11-05  NULL
```

I'm stuck in the

- If more than one price is valid for one product, price with higher `price.priceID` should be chosen

requirement, which stems from an outlandish business requirement for more than one valid prices for any given product for a period of time. My sql fu is extremely poor, I went as far as:

```
SELECT
    product.*,
    price.*
FROM
    product
LEFT JOIN
    price
ON 
    price.productID = product.productID
    AND price.started <= NOW() 
    AND (
        price.expires IS NULL
        OR price.expires >= NOW()
    )
```

Which of course for for `NOW() == 2011-11-09` results in:

```
productID   priceID     productID   started     expires
-------------------------------------------------------
1           1           1           2011-11-05  NULL    
1           2           1           2011-11-05  2011-11-20
2           3           2           2011-11-05  NULL
3           4           3           2011-11-05  NULL
```

---

**Clarifications (based on comments and answers):**

- The requirements are uniquely weird, but valid. Overlapping intervals is an actual business requirement, sometimes I need to show all prices (easy) and sometimes just the one, the more recent (what I'm asking about).
- Can't do much to change the datamodel.
- I'm looking for the whole join, if possible. (or hints on how subqueries can be integrated into the final join)
- I'd prefer solutions based on standard SQL (ANSI / ISO) or MySQL.

Comment: I couldn't think of a more descriptive title, if you think something better please feel free to edit.

Comment: Can there be more than one price for a product that is valid that has the same price?

Comment: @RedFilter There can be any number of valid prices for each product. I'm looking for a way to get the _most_ valid (for luck of a better term) based on the four criteria.

Comment: There should be a constraint to forbid overlapping intervals. That would avoid this kind of mess.

Comment: @wildplasser Overlapping intervals is an actual business requirement. Cant avoid it, unfortunately.

Comment: A product cannot have two prices at the same time. (maybe you need another layer of indirection, eg: "offer" or "bundle" ). Also: you need to avoid intervals that are inclusive at both sides. Instead, use "now >= begin_date AND (now < end_date OR end_date IS NULL)"

Comment: @wildplasser Unfortunately in my case a product can have a few valid prices. It's not an offer thing, they are all equally valid prices. And it's not a client's idiosyncrasy, it's a legal requirement that's too _localized_ to discuss here. Please note that products are not _ordinary_ products, I've used the term to best describe the requirements.

Comment: Well, in that case you have omitted at least one candidate key element from your description.

Comment: "If more than one price is valid for one product, price with higher price.priceID should be chosen". : you are misusing the (non existent) ordering of a surrogate key as a tie-breaker. Your datamodel and/or requirements are flawed.

Comment: @wildplasser The tie breaker is used in only one instance (a report where it makes sense to show only one price), otherwise the app shows all valid prices. The requirements are strange, but I can't do much about them as they are valid (unfortunately). The datamodel I inherited and I really don't have a choice to change it (and it does reflect the requirements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    pro.*
  , pri.*
FROM 
    product AS pro
  JOIN
    price AS pri
      ON pri.priceID =
         ( SELECT p.priceID
           FROM price p 
           WHERE p.productID = pro.productID
             AND p.started <= CURRENT_DATE() 
             AND ( p.expires IS NULL
                OR p.expires >= CURRENT_DATE()
                 )
           ORDER BY p.priceId DESC 
           LIMIT 1
         )
```

Comment: Excellent, this works! Thanks! Substituting `SELECT p.priceID` with `SELECT MAX(p.priceID)` and getting rid of `ORDER BY p.priceId DESC` seems to be a little bit faster.

Comment: Different conditions in the subquery will need different indexes for best performance.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated**

The following (complete) query should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    product.*,
    price.*
FROM
    product, 
   (SELECT price.* FROM price 
        WHERE price.started <= NOW() 
        AND 
            (price.expires IS NULL
            OR price.expires >= NOW())
    GROUP BY price.productId
    BY price.priceId DESC LIMIT 1) AS `price`
WHERE price.productID = product.productID;
```

Comment: This is only the sub-query, not the entire query.

Comment: @rich.okelly Well that does get the price right, but my actual problem is with the join. Any suggestions on how the subquery would fit into a join?

Comment: @YannisRizos apologies, I misunderstood the full requirement! Answer now updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    p.*,
  ( SELECT 
        TOP 1 pr.price 
    FROM price pr 
    WHERE pr.productID = p.productID 
      AND pr.started <= NOW() 
      AND (  pr.expires IS NULL 
          OR pr.expires >= NOW()) 
    ORDER BY 
        pr.productID DESC
  ) AS price
FROM product p
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken SELECT TOP is part of Transact-SQL. Any solution for ANSI SQL?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to avoid subqueries, you may try the following statement:

```
SELECT
   product.*,
   price.*,
   MAX(price.priceID)
FROM
   product
LEFT JOIN
   price
ON 
   price.productID = product.productID
   AND price.started <= NOW() 
   AND (
      price.expires IS NULL
      OR price.expires >= NOW()
   )
GROUP BY price.productID
```

The GROUP BY will force only distinct products in the result with the max priceID. Hope it helps!

Comment: It seems to me that in your query MAX(price.priceID) is just extra info and not a criterion in the join. This would still return more than one lines per product.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH pc AS (
    SELECT pc1.priceid, pc1.productid
    , pc1.started, pc1.expires
    FROM tmp.price pc1
    WHERE pc1.started <= now()
    AND (pc1.expires IS NULL OR pc1.expires > now() )
    AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
        FROM tmp.price pcx
        WHERE pcx.productid = pc1.productid
        AND pcx.started <= now()
            AND (pcx.expires IS NULL OR pcx.expires > now() )
        AND pcx.priceid > pc1.priceid
        )
    )
SELECT pd.productid
    , pd.productname
    , pc.started
    , pc.expires
FROM pc
JOIN tmp.product pd ON pc.productid = pd.productid
    ;
```

A CTE is a nameless view. If your DBMS does not support CTEs, you could make the first (CTE) part of the query into a named view; the subsyntax is the same. YMMV.